# "site users" web part sharepoint 2013 not available

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-addin

"Site users" web part not coming when trying to add web part on my new site collection. Please let me know, if i need to active any feature for this?

Comment: what is site users on your original site collection?
if it is a list then you have to make that same list for the new site collection.

Answer (score 0):

Go to a site where the webpart is available.
Site Settings --> Webparts --> Export the MSMembers.dwp file and Import it on the site where the webpart is missing.

Comment: Can you please give some more brief explanation for your answer.